# Is it possible to access service class method from functional interface in Spring Java 8?

Tags: java, spring, functional-interface

**I want to access service class method from functional interface in Spring Java 8. Is it possible ?**

```
public interface UserProfile extends Supplier<UserProfileDto> {

//  This is working
    static UserProfile getMyId() {
        return () ->
                new UserProfileDto(
                        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName(),
                        "", "", "");
    }

    static UserProfile getMyProfile() {
        return () -> 
    }
}

@Service("userProfileService")
public class UserProfileServiceImpl implements UserProfileService {

    private final UserProfileRepo userProfileRepo;

    @Autowired
    public UserProfileServiceImpl(@Qualifier("userProfileSql") UserProfileRepo userProfileRepo) {
        this.userProfileRepo = userProfileRepo;
    }

    @Override
    public Optional<UserProfileDto> getUserProfileById(String userId) {
        return userProfileRepo.selectUserProfileById(userId);
    }
}
```

I Want to call service class method "getUserProfileById(SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName())" in getMyProfile() in UserProfile. Is it possible ?

Comment: No it is not possible.

Comment: No. It is an interface method so no.

Comment: You can define a static member of type `Function<String, UserProfile>` in `UserProfile` that you set from the service after it is initialized. But this is so unclean I won't post it as an answer.

Comment: Thanx.. If I use SPEL to solve it. Is it possible ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't access the service class method from the functional interface